# javascript onclick even handler reveals form

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am wanting to pass a variable through to another form that will reveal itself when a certain radio button is clicked. However not sure the best way to do this as do not want to refresh the page.

the javascript for the form opening is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".col3flex").css("display","none");
        $(".category").click(function(){

        if ($('input[name=category]:checked')) {
            $(".col3flex").slideDown("fast"); 

        } else {
            $(".col3flex").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
     });
});
```

what i need to do now, is pass the radio button value to be picked up by my php select statement in order to display the correct values.

How would i implement this please

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're having trouble with the event handler and then checking for the value of the radio button. I think this is what you need (I assume that ".category" is the radio button?)

```
$('.category').change(function() {

    if ($(this).val('checked') === 'checked') {
        // do whatever...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load some backend-informations via PHP you won't come around AJAX - especially if you need such informations while not reloading the page.

You need to send the AJAX-request and fill the needed elements which its information before sliding the `.col3flex`-element down.

If thats not quite what you wanted, you need to go further into details regarding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can send an ajax request to any other page that will render you other select. At on click event just send an ajax request to some other page

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".col3flex").css("display","none");
    $(".category").click(function(){

    if ($('input[name=category]:checked')) {
        var url='somepage.php';
        var data=$(".category").val();
        $.ajax({url:url,data:data,type:'POST',success:function(data){
         //here you will just populate the html response sent by `somepage.php` say your select has id='select' then
          $('#select').html(data));
         }});
        $(".col3flex").slideDown("fast"); 

    } else {
        $(".col3flex").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
 });
 });
```

And your `somepage.php` file will get the `post` data and generate the dropdown

```
   if(isset($_POST))
    {
      ?>
       //Your html for generating a select statement
       <?
    }
```

Comment: there is an error in this syntax around the ajax and tried a few different ways an will not work

Comment: @meohmy I have edited the syntax for `ajax` request please try again

Comment: thanks for this but does not solve any of the problems i am having

Comment: @meohmy now what you problem you are having? Please sate what you have done and what you are facing?

Comment: there is a syntax error still on the select line, also, i need the page to not refresh, just to show a particlluar form that is determined by the value of the radio button.